# Configuring Pub/Sub destination for ad-hoc Transcoder API job requests in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-transcoder

Using the Node JS client, I can't get the Transcoder API to accept the pub/sub destination.

The documentation variously says to configure the [`pubsub_destination`](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/how-to/create-pub-sub) field or the [`pubsubDestination`](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/reference/rest/v1/JobConfig) field, but neither appear to work when creating a job using the `createJob` method (following and extending the [example](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/samples/transcoder-create-job-from-ad-hoc) for ad-hoc job creation).

```js
const config = {
      parent: client.locationPath(projectId, location),
      job: {
        inputUri: inputUri,
        outputUri: outputUri,
        config: {
          elementaryStreams: [
            {
              key: 'video-stream0',
              videoStream: {
                h264: {
                  heightPixels: 360,
                  widthPixels: 640,
                  bitrateBps: 550000,
                  frameRate: 60
                }
              }
            },
            {
              key: 'audio-stream0',
              audioStream: {
                codec: 'aac',
                bitrateBps: 64000
              }
            }
          ],
          muxStreams: [
            {
              elementaryStreams: ['video-stream0', 'audio-stream0'],
              key: 'sd',
              filename: 'sd.mp4',
              container: 'mp4'
            }
          ]
        },
        pubsubDestination: { topic: `projects/${projectId}/topics/transcoder` }
      }
    };
return await client.createJob(request);
```

The job gets created and completes successfully, but the config field of the created job shows `"pubsubDestination": null`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hello @drzax. If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried creating a job using an ad-hoc configuration [template](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/how-to/jobs#create_jobs_ad_hoc) with a [pubsubDestination](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/reference/rest/v1/JobConfig) field in the jobConfig and successfully received the job status updates from the Transcoder API to Pub/Sub topic. Try the following code for your requirement:

```
projectId = 'my-project-id';
location = 'us-central1';
inputUri = 'gs://my-bucket/my-video-file';
outputUri = 'gs://my-bucket/my-output-folder/';

// Imports the Transcoder library
const {TranscoderServiceClient} =
 require('@google-cloud/video-transcoder').v1;

// Instantiates a client
const transcoderServiceClient = new TranscoderServiceClient();

async function createJobFromAdHoc() {
 // Construct request
 const request = {
   parent: transcoderServiceClient.locationPath(projectId, location),
   job: {
     inputUri: inputUri,
     outputUri: outputUri,
     config: {
       elementaryStreams: [
         {
           key: 'video-stream0',
           videoStream: {
             h264: {
               heightPixels: 360,
               widthPixels: 640,
               bitrateBps: 550000,
               frameRate: 60,
             },
           },
         },
         {
           key: 'video-stream1',
           videoStream: {
             h264: {
               heightPixels: 720,
               widthPixels: 1280,
               bitrateBps: 2500000,
               frameRate: 60,
             },
           },
         },
         {
           key: 'audio-stream0',
           audioStream: {
             codec: 'aac',
             bitrateBps: 64000,
           },
         },
       ],
       muxStreams: [
         {
           key: 'sd',
           container: 'mp4',
           elementaryStreams: ['video-stream0', 'audio-stream0'],
         },
         {
           key: 'hd',
           container: 'mp4',
           elementaryStreams: ['video-stream1', 'audio-stream0'],
         },
       ],
       pubsubDestination: {
           topic: 'projects/{project-ID}/topics/{topic-ID}'
       },
     },
   },
 };
  // Run request
 const [response] = await transcoderServiceClient.createJob(request);
 console.log(`Job: ${response.name}`);
}

createJobFromAdHoc();
```

Result:

[image]